# How to connect to a ssh remote server after a sudo vpnc connection, all automatically ? (bash)

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I'm actually working on vi and I want to make a script which connects me to a vpnc (and automatically enters the password), and then, connects me to a ssh distant server.

I made this, but it's not working:

```
#! /usr/bin/

set force_conservative 1;

set timeout 2
spawn sudo vpnc
expect "password: $"
send "xxx"

spawn ssh marpic@192.xxx.xxx.xxx
expect "password: $"
send "xxx"
interact
```

I want to implement this so I can later add my copyfiles.sh script which copies the files on the ssh server to my PC.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? An error message (which), nothing happens, ...? How do you run the script? In which shell? ...

Comment: it means that i have no error message

Comment: And now i executed it once, it tells me that i've no permissions to execute it, but i've applied chmod 771 on the script

Comment: The first obvious problem is that this is not a bash script, because no program is defined to run it. Only `/usr/bin` which is a directory. So start with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, then show what doesn't work. But the rest suggests that you actually didn't intend to write a Bash script, but maybe an `expect` script instead?

Answer (score 0):

check your first line.
make sure you invoke the shell correctly.
#!/usr/bin/*bash*    is the path correct?